# Difference between df.reindex() and df.set_index() methods in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, reindex

I was confused by this, which is very simple but I didn't immediately find the answer on StackOverflow:

- `df.set_index('xcol')` makes the column `'xcol'` become the index (when it is a column of df).
- `df.reindex(myList)`, however, takes indexes from outside the dataframe, for example, from a list named `myList` that we defined somewhere else.

However, `df.reindex(myList)` also changes values to NAs. A simple alternative is: `df.index = myList`

I hope this post clarifies it! Additions to this post are also welcome!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can see the difference on a simple example. Let's consider this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],'b': [3, 4]})
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Indexes are then 0 and 1

If you use `set_index` with the column 'a' then the indexes are 1 and 2. If you do `df.set_index('a').loc[1,'b']`, you will get 3.

Now if you want to use `reindex` with the same indexes 1 and 2 such as `df.reindex([1,2])`, you will get 4.0 when you do `df.reindex([1,2]).loc[1,'b']`

What happend is that `set_index` has replaced the previous indexes (0,1) with (1,2) (values from column 'a') without touching the order of values in the column 'b'

```
df.set_index('a')
   b
a   
1  3
2  4
```

while `reindex` change the indexes but keeps the values in column 'b' associated to the indexes in the original df

```
df.reindex(df.a.values).drop('a',1) # equivalent to df.reindex(df.a.values).drop('a',1)
     b
1  4.0
2  NaN
# drop('a',1) is just to not care about column a in my example
```

Finally, `reindex` change the order of indexes without changing the values of the row associated to each index, while `set_index` will change the indexes with the values of a column, without touching the order of the other values in the dataframe

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Just a brief usage comment, pandas recommends using `at` rather than `loc` for single-cell indexing: `df.at[1, 'b']`. Loc is generally meant for accessing ranges.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add, the undo to [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) would be [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method (more or less):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],'b': [3, 4]})
print (df)

df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
print(df)

df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
print(df)
```

---

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
   b
a   
1  3
2  4
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides great answer from Ben. T, I would like to give one more example of how they are different when you use `reindex` and `set_index` to an index column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 2],'b': [3, 5, 4],'c': [5, 7, 6]})

print(testdf)
print(testdf.set_index(np.random.permutation(testdf.index)))
print(testdf.reindex(np.random.permutation(testdf.index)))
```

Output:

- With `set_index`, when `index` column (the first column) is shuffled, the order of other columns are kept intact
- With `reindex`, the order of rows are changed accordingly to the shuffle of `index` column.

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  3  5  7
2  2  4  6
   a  b  c
1  1  3  5
2  3  5  7
0  2  4  6
   a  b  c
2  2  4  6
1  3  5  7
0  1  3  5
```